# Symfony 2 collection, delete all images by delete parent

Tags: php, symfony

I'm testing collection field in Symfony2 and I have problem with delete parent.

I use example from symfony documentatnion so I have 2 classes ( task and tag ) buy with relation 1:n and tag have file field.

When I remove tag from task, file is removes but when I delete task, image doesn't remove. 
I think I know why it that work.
But I don't know what I should to add to my class.

My classes :

**Task class**

```
class Task
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $description;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="task", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $tags;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
}

public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}

public function addTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $tag->setTask($this);
    $tag->upload($this);
    $this->tags->add($tag);
}
public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
    $tag->removeImg();
}
```

Tag class

```
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
public $file;

/**
* @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
*/
public $name;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="tags")
*/
protected $task;

public function setTask(\MGraphics\FrontendBundle\Entity\Task $task)
{
    $this->task = $task;
    return $this;
}    
public function getTask()
{
    return $this->task;
}    
public function removeImg(){
   if(file_exists($this->getUploadRootDir().$this->name))
    @unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().$this->name);
}    
public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../'.$this->getUploadDir();
}
protected function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'uploads/';
}
public function upload()
{
    $this->name = trim(date("dmyGis").rand(1,99999999).'_'.$this->file->getClientOriginalName());
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->name);
    $this->file = null;
}
```

My delete controller

```
    $entity = $em->getRepository('MGraphicsFrontendBundle:Task')->findOneById($id);
    $em->remove($entity);
    $em->flush();
```

Do I have to create foreach and use function removeImg for any tag in task?
Why on edit, function "removeTag" work but on delete, no?

Comment: Try on delete cascade

Answer (score 0):

Change your mapping for Tags property to cascade delete, too

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="task", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * joinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
 protected $tags;
```